# Right way to create urls in Django

Tags: python, django, django-urls

In Django I have my app where I place information about countries and cities of these countries. This is my model.py file:

```
class Country(models.Model):
        class Meta:
                verbose_name_plural = u'Countries'

        name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        slug = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        description = models.TextField(max_length=10000, blank=True)

        def __unicode__(self):
                return self.name

class City(models.Model):
        class Meta:
                verbose_name_plural = u'Cities'

        name = models.CharField(u'city', max_length=200)
        slug = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
        description = models.TextField(max_length=10000, blank=True)
        country = models.ForeignKey('Country', blank=True, null=True)

        def __unicode__(self):
                return self.name
```

I have the detail view of my country, in this view there is a list of cities of this country(views.py):

```
def CountryDetail(request, slug):
        country = get_object_or_404(Country, slug=slug)
        list_cities = City.objects.filter(country=country)
        return render(request, 'country/country.html', {'country':country, 'list_cities':list_cities})
```

this is my urls.py:

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[-_\w]+)/$', views.CountryDetail, name='country'),
```

I want to create a url of cities which contain a slug of the country and a slug of the city, for example `domain.com/spain/barcelona/`.

So I created the detail view of the city, and it's looks like this:

```
def CityDetail(request, resortslug):
        country = Country.objects.get(slug=countryslug)
        city = get_object_or_404(City, country=country, slug=cityslug)
        return render(request, 'country/city.html', {'country':country, 'city':city})
```

Here is my urls.py for city detail:

```
url(r'^(?P<countryslug>[-_\w]+)/(?P<cityslug>[-_\w]+)$', views.CityDetail, name='resort'),
```

And this is how it looks like in my html file detail of the country that links to the cities:

```
<h1>{{country.name}}</h1>
<p>{{country.description}}</p>
<h2>Cities</h2>
{% for city in list_cities %}
   <a href="/{{country.slug}}/{{city.slug}}">
      <p>{{city.name}}</p>
   </a>
{% endfor %}
```

But when I click on the link of the url of the city, I get a 404 error.

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://domain.com/spain/barcelona
Using the URLconf defined in myproject.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
The current URL, spain/barcelona, didn't match any of these.
```

Here is my url.py from my project

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^country/', include('country.urls')),
```

Please help me understand why this happens, thank you.

Comment: What kind of 404 error do you get? With DEBUG enabled, it should either say that it tried your URL patterns and none matched, or it should say "No City matches the given query" (from get_object_or_404).

Comment: Can you post the contents of your myproject/urls.py file?

Comment: So, to clarify, you currently have a template/view setup that lists all the cities for a country, where the country is passed in through the URL. That page works. The country template provides links to city details in the URL format "country/city", however, Django is not finding a match for that URL. This would point that there is something wrong with your city detail URLS.py

Comment: already edit the post

Comment: What is the URL you are hitting for your country view?

Also, have you tried "http ://domain.com/country/spain/barcelona". Does anything come up?

Comment: Yes thank you very much, I found my bug. You can add it to the answer

Comment: Glad I could be of help. It looks like Mathias provided the answer post before I got back

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your project includes your app's URLs under the `country/` prefix, the city page is available as `country/spain/barcelona`, or http://domain.com/country/spain/barcelona.